# What's a good way of batch converting tracker files?

Tags: mp3, audio-conversion, ogg

So, as the title says, I would like to know a good way to convert tracker files (`*.mod`, `*.xm`, `*.s3m`, et cetera) to a format like `*.mp3` or `*.ogg`.

A command-line solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg supports each of those formats. You could convert all of them with a bash loop, such as `for i in *.mod; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -b:a 320k "${i%mod}mp3"; done`

Comment: What's the best stackexchange site for asking about compiling ffmpeg from source?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to do this on Windows, the command `for %G in (*.xm) do ffmpeg -i "%G" -b:a 320k -f mp3 "%G.mp3"` works for me, modified from the above bash script.