# How to convert xm file to mp3 without using complex software?

Tags: mp3

I have some .xm files which I have trouble converting.

No online software engines seems to be able to convert them as they might or might not be protected as they are supposed to be paid.

Are there any software engines out there which are easy to use to convert them? I saw another question related to this but I have no idea how to use avconv.

I uploaded one of the xm music files in the following link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=34315811444656085959

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good way of batch converting tracker files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1147919/whats-a-good-way-of-batch-converting-tracker-files)

Comment: Except it's actually not a tracker file at all...

Comment: @grawity Well, the question I mention refers as *.xm being a tracker file but looks like it's a [extended module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XM_(file_format)) file. It has an answer so maybe it can be helpful

Comment: @CaldeiraG: No, it's a proprietary format file that only _happens to be_ named *.xm because it comes from some app called "Xiami". So far I haven't been able to figure out how to decode it, but it has ID3v2.3 tags and text "ifmt MP3" at the top, and looks nothing like a real XM tracker module would look.

Comment: @grawity understood! :) thanks for the detailed explanation.